# Converting KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT(.NET) to KeyEvent/Char(Java), JNA

Tags: c#, java, .net, msdn, jna

So, basically what i'm doing is using JNA to set a LowLevelKeyboardProc Keyboard hook, everything works perfectly fine, i can get the values exactly like i want them in java, but the problem i get is when trying to convert to chars, it becomes extremely ennoying handling caps locks, SHIFT keys and tons of other things like everything thats not a-z 0-9 on the keyboard, i was wondering if there is a easier way to do the conversion?
heres the details of what I'm getting from the hook every time a key is pressed
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644967(v=VS.85).aspx
, i Figured it might be best to find a way to manually generate a KeyEvent(Not char, since i need something to handle things like F keys, caps lock button, CTRL button etc etc).

Any help i can get is highly appriciated!.

Comment: If you solved your problem it's be nice if you posted your solution.

Answer (score 0):

The Abbot project (http://abbot.sf.net) has a system for mapping keycodes to keychars, using predefined keyboard mappings (it generates a wide variety of keystrokes and records the resulting character output).   However, Java does not provide a way for "predicting" the resulting character output given a particular key code.

There may be something within the MS libraries.

Comment: this was somewhat helpful, i ended up writing my own solution